# Adding filter to the title without affecting the menu title

Tags: plugin-development, filters

Hi I'm having problems with the `the_title` filter here's the code that I have:

```
function zen_title_filter($title){

    if(is_singular()){
        if(!empty($_GET['asin'])){
            if($title == 'Product Details Page' || $title == 'Compare Products Page'){
                $title = zen_get_titles();

            }

        }

    }

    return $title;
}

add_filter('the_title', 'zen_title_filter');
```

As you can see this filter updates both the menu title for the product details page and compare products page. But the behavior that I'm expecting is that it should only update the title of the post itself but not the menu title which in this case is also the same as the post title. Any ideas?

[image]

**UPDATE**

I'm actually generating the page on the fly. Using a page as the template. So the post id is the id of the page. What I'm doing is adding filter to the content and completely replace the content of the page using the new content:

```
add_filter('the_content', function($content){
  if(is_page('compare')){
   $asin = esc_attr($_GET['asin']);
   $data = get_data($asin);
   $smarty->assign('item_data', $data);
   $content = $smarty->fetch('file.tpl');
  }
  return $content;
});
```

Comment: The answer to this question is here and uses `in_the_loop()`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13456521/why-the-title-filter-is-also-applied-in-menu-title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're generating things on the fly, we can use a global flag to let us know when we want the title applied.

```
add_filter('the_content', function($content){
  if(is_page('compare')){
   global $asin_doing_template;

   // mark that we're doing a template
   $asin_doing_template = true;

   $asin = esc_attr($_GET['asin']);
   $data = get_data($asin);
   $smarty->assign('item_data', $data);
   $content = $smarty->fetch('file.tpl');

   // set it back to false
   $asin_doing_template = false;
  }
  return $content;
});

function zen_title_filter( $title ){
    global $asin_doing_template;

    if( is_singular() && $asin_doing_template ){
        if( $title == 'Product Details Page' || $title == 'Compare Products Page' ){
            $title = zen_get_titles();
        }
    }

    return $title;
}

add_filter( 'the_title', 'zen_title_filter' );
```

Let me know if that does it!

Comment: it doesn't seem to work. I'm actually generating the post on the fly so the post id is actually the id of the current page. Please see the update in my question.

Comment: I've updated my answer based on the auto-generation factor. Let me know how it looks.

Comment: that would update both the menu title and the post title. but anyway thanks for your help, I guess I'll just modify the menu title via javascript once the page loads

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
function change_title($title) {
    if( in_the_loop() && !is_archive() ) { //skipping Menu Items and Archive page
        return $title.'<span class="after_title_ss9"></span>';              
    }

    return $title;

}
add_filter('the_title', array($this, 'change_title'), 10, 2);
```